# Unable to paste any text or file in my pc - Clipboard error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clipboard

I am using a code to capture text of an application.

When I start the application I cant to copy and paste any text or file in my pc.I know Why I am getting this error its because the clipboard is cleared for every second or two because I have kept the code in a loop.Its a big problem for me and my clients if they use my application in their pc.I want to know can we create a new clipboard for only my aplication use rather than using my desktop clipboard or can anyone provide my any solution for my problem.The code I am using is

```
        try
        {
            IEnumerator enumerator;
            MainModule.StrData = "";
            try
            {
                enumerator = this.chkListbox_odin1.CheckedIndices.GetEnumerator();
                IntPtr parentWnd = FindWindow((null), cboWindows.Text);
                IntPtr mdiClientWnd = FindWindowEx(parentWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "MDIClient", "");
                IntPtr marketwatchWnd = FindWindowEx(mdiClientWnd, IntPtr.Zero, null, windowname);
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    object objectValue = enumerator.Current;
                    this.WindowText(marketwatchWnd);
                }
                //    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
                //  Application.DoEvents();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            Clipboard.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(exception1.Message);
        }
```

Here are some image of my problem

I can Copy while i run my application.
[image]

But when I try to paste

Paste is not highlighting,
[image]

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: its not an error.my problem is i cant copy and paste because the clipboard is busy in capturing the another application text I mean when i am trying to copy and paste the paste menustrip is not highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will be/are using SendKeys to execute a copy operation once you have found or brought focus to the window whose text you are trying to copy.  (Your current code is only clearing the clipboard, not putting anything on it or using its data)  You might try looking into the method used on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873404/get-text-from-another-application).  That method will allow you to skip using the clipboard at all and will have the added benefit of not requiring you to change window focus which could be just as bad of a problem for your end users as constantly clearing the clipboard.  (This part assumes your using SendKeys to affect the clipboard, which only works on the currently focused window I believe)