# Get text of a textbox of an application from another application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I want to read the value of a textbox. For example, "UserID" of [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) from an application in C#. How can I do it?

Put in another way, I want to write an application that read the user id and password from TeamViewer.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Please clarify it.

Comment: for example i want to write an application that read UserID and Password from teamviewer

Comment: That sounds like malware. Why would you expect an application to let you steal user passwords? Why would you expect to steal them? If you want them, ask the user.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take help of `user32.dll` functions. Its an unsafe OS level library and allows you to access other running Applications on the platform. There is one more StackOverflow solution related to your problem at: [How to read another windows from a different program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685002/how-to-read-another-windows-from-a-different-program) and [Get text from another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873404/get-text-from-another-application)