# How to fill textbox of thirdparty app using c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

My app written in c# (winforms) launches a third party using Process.start().

After launch, I need to fill in some information in **Search Textbox** of Third party app. So how to identify the textbox of thirdpaty app? how to fill info in it?

Any clue or guidance? Keywords to search for?

Comment: Please go through this link.
It will help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019790/how-to-find-a-child-of-a-parent-unmanaged-win32-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) Library.

Using either [UISPY.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx) of [Inspect.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) find the automationid , name etc any
parameter that can uniquely indentify the TextBox. One you have done this
you can do something like this, assuming you know the automation id.

```
string automationId = "ThirdyPartBox";
string newTextBoxValue = "foobar";
var condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, automationId);
var textBox = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.SubTree , condition);
ValuePattern vPattern = (ValuePattern)textBox.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern);
vPattern.SetValue(newTextBoxValue);
```

Maybe the textbox is not uniquely identifiable by itself , you can use conditions like process id , parent container id etc to pin point it.

To Click a Button. Find the automation element first using a condition of your choice and then

```
InvokePattern clickButton = (InvokePattern)buttonElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern);
clickButton.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thanks parapua: How to send enter key (To press the Search Button)?

Comment: Isn't the UI Automation for WPF applications only?

Comment: @afaolek Not really it can handle both WPF and win32 api apps