# Extract data from other app gui in Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I'd like to create application to combine measurements from two car systems and plot it.
One is external lambda sensor, second is aftermarket ECU for propane-butane conversion.
One could deliver AFR information, second RPM and engine load.

Unfortunately those app don't provide any api. Apps have simple GUI, I thought that maybe extracting data from it could be solution. Is there any easy and reliable method to extract numbers/texts from other application? I'd like to use C++ or C# on Windows.

Comment: Maybe you can grab the Window image, and process it using OCR on your Application.

Comment: If there is no published API to get that data, then anything you come up with will be a hack that is going to break every single time the creators of those applications change as much as a comma in their apps. Better talk to the vendors and agree on a stable API you can use.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to retrieve the values directly from memory. Get the window handle of the application, and traverse its child windows until you find the windows (fields) which contain the information you're looking for. From what I read, the difficult part is finding the class names of the forms you're interested in. You can write this logic yourself using [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx), or use [Managed Windows API](http://mwinapi.sourceforge.net/).

More information:

[How to find a child of a parent unmanaged win32 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019790/how-to-find-a-child-of-a-parent-unmanaged-win32-app)

[How to read another windows from a different program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685002/how-to-read-another-windows-from-a-different-program)

[How to find a child of a parent unmanaged win32 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019790/how-to-find-a-child-of-a-parent-unmanaged-win32-app)

Comment: That's a ginormous hack. Would you *really* do that in production code?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: No. Why assume this is production code? OP asked a question which only hacks could answer; I provided a hack.